# How to disable an action from template hooks in Wordpress' Woocommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Here's a part of codes in `wc-template-hooks.php`:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_output_product_data_tabs', 10 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_upsell_display', 15 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_output_related_products', 20 );
```

Here's the code from `content-single-product.php`

```
do_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary' );
```

What code should I put in `content-single-product.php` to remove `woocommerce_output_related_products`  without editing the `wc-template-hooks.php`.

Sorry, I'm new in PHP. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

You dont have to put it in content-single-product.php, try adding it to functions.php and if you just need to remove it on a single products page use woocommerce conditional functions to allow it only on the pages you want. for instance.

```
<?php if(is_product()){ 
remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_output_related_products', 20 ); }?>
```

Answer (score 2):

I have tried all above solutions but not working. Woo-commerce Version 3.4.1

Working Code, Added in child theme in `functions.php`

```
add_filter('woocommerce_product_related_posts_query', '__return_empty_array', 20);
```

Answer (score 1):

If I correctly understood your question, put this in the `functions.php` inside your theme folder:

```
<?php 
function woocommerce_remove_related_products() {
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_output_related_products', 20);
}

add_action('woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_remove_related_products'); 
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can remove action try adding it to **functions.php** -

```
add_filter( 'body_class', 'remove_action_from_woocommerce');
function remove_action_from_woocommerce()
{
 if(is_product()){ 
  remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_output_related_products', 20 ); }
   }
}
```

> Here you can get WooCommerce Action and Filter Hook
>   -https://docs.woothemes.com/wc-apidocs/hook-docs.html